# How to get xml output from the listed array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Edited:I was a building a webscraper in php ,and i would like to get the array contents outputs as xml or json format.

i have fetched the contents into array,but could not able to write it to xml file.

my input array is this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] =>  

100GB  of 5G  data                                 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] =>  

18GB  of 4G  data                                             
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] =>  

100GB  of 5G  data                                          
        )


)
```

i want it to save as xml/json file.

How i can do this???

Thanks for the suggestions in the question

Comment: A little tip: please share `var_export` output for your values instead of `print_r`. With `var_export` we can simply copy the contents to an editor and recreate the variable. Also, what exactly is the problem with your code? Does it throw errors? Is content not what you expect?

Comment: Yes ,i have modified with var_export.

Comment: Actually , i want to get the array as xml file,I tried some codes,but it throws errors,can i get a proper way how to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for checking.

I can achieve it to output as json with following code:

`file_put_contents("my_array.json", json_encode($array));`

also,
`file_put_contents( '/some/file/data.php', '<?php return '.var_export( $data_array, true ).";\n" );`

I have chose json instead of xml.